# Установка ipa файла в айфон с помощью iTools. Ошибка проверки

Tags: windows, ios, iphone

Пытаюсь установить приложение на айфон с помощью утилиты iTools. По [этой](http://www.lg-finance.ru/VistaCalciOsInstruction.html) инструкции. Выдаёт ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что ему надо и как исправить?

Comment: Это приложение для jailbroken устройств?

Comment: Ты нашел решение данной проблемы?